# MS Teams Message Extension submitTask not working in iPhone Teams App

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have created a message extension with the custom web form, it fails to send any data back to the bot on `microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask`. It just closes the form, and the bot submit action method does not receive any data. No issues with other clients like web, windows, or mac. Any way to debug or look into log files on the mobile?

Event tried with this [sample code for message extension](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-task-module-nodejs) and used the compiled [TaskModule.zip](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-task-module-nodejs/blob/master/TaskModule.zip) package, it's also not working in the Teams iOS application.

Comment: Could you please take a look at [Task module sample code v4](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/54.teams-task-module)?

Comment: The sample code is sending an adaptive card to the channel and the action triggered by the card itself, I'm trying it from a web form, which uses Teams JS SDK. Is there anything in particular, you are pointing to in that sample?

Comment: For the Web form, you can submit the data using microsoftTeams.task.submitTask(yourData,submitHandler).

Comment: Don't know if you've managed to resolve yet. But I was having similar problem until I realised I was using the botId instead of the appID as the second param for submitTask.

Answer (score -1):

try sending only one parameter into submitTask.You could do something like this.
 `microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask(yourObj);`